# If matrix $AB=A$, does it mean B must be an identity matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

If matrix multiplication $AB=A$, does it mean $B$ must be an identity matrix?
If not, why? What conditions?

$A$ is not a zero matrix.

Comment: If $A$ is the zero matrix, then...

Comment: Did you think about this question, even a little bit?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotent_matrix

Answer (score 13):

$AB=A$ means $A(B-I)=0$ so the condition is precisely that the image of $B-I$ is contained in $\ker A$. Unless $A$ is injective, this does not force $B=I$.

Comment: What do you mean by "injective"?

Comment: Being injective means (for linear maps) sending _only_ the zero vector to $0$, in other words having $\{0\}$ as kernel.

Comment: If $A \in \Bbb M_{n \times m}(\Bbb R)$, then $\ker A = \{{\bf v} \in \Bbb R^m \ : \ A{\bf v} = 0\}$, where ${\bf v}$ is viewed as a column vector.

Answer (score 6):

Let 
$$
A=B=\left(\begin{matrix} 1&0\\ 0&0\end{matrix}\right)
$$
then
$$
AB=\left(\begin{matrix} 1&0\\ 0&0\end{matrix}\right).
$$

Nevertheless, if $A$ is non-singular, then $B=I$. If $A$ is singular, then we can always find an example such us the one above.

Comment: That's exactly what I said, with projector :)

Answer (score 5):

The equality $AB = A$ holds if and only if each row of $A$ is either an all zero row  or an eigenvector with eigenvalue $1$ for $B.$ Hence, as long as $B$ has $1$ as an eigenvalue, we can construct a matrix $A$ of rank $1$ with $AB = A.$

Comment: More precisely, each row of $A$ has to be a [_left_-eigenvector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors#Left_and_right_eigenvectors) of $B$ for eigenvalue$~1$. But indeed as long as $B$ has such an eigenvalue, one can choose $A$ nonzero.

Answer (score 2):

Another example is to consider the case : A= B

=> $A^2$ = A , so if A is a projector (which is not the identity), you can find that B=A verify your equality, while B is not the identity

In fact, if you let C be the projection on Ker(A), and B= I+C

A*B=A*(I+C) = A +A*C =A . If A is not iversible, C is not 0, and B is not the identity.